# is it possible to implement nested ModalBottomSheetLayout in sheetContent (JetpackCompose)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

i am implementing modal bottom sheet dialog , i do not want to close previous open Dialog that should visible until i do not close. that should be open (N) no of Time Nested  ModalBottomSheetLayout

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(sheetState = bottomState,
        scrimColor = Color.Transparent,
        sheetElevation = 4.dp,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 12.dp, topEnd = 12.dp),
        sheetContent = { 
             Screen1()
        }{
           MainScreen()
        })
```

i want multiple dialog without closing previous one.

Comment: I don't think so we can do it but If you still want to this kind of stuff then use custom dialog and show with animation like bottomsheet

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome library -> https://github.com/dokar3/sheets

It will definitely help you achieve your objective as it uses dialog windows which appear like bottomsheets. It can display multiple bottomsheets over another without collapsing the earlier ones.

Comment: thank you @pravesh Singh i will definitely try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).